# Imagesharp resizes my image larger than the original

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, webp, imagesharp

I have a program in **.NETCoreApp 3.1** and I use the **SixLabors.ImageSharp** version 2.1.3 to handle the processing of images in our CDN for all our sites.
The application run in docker container linux and for testing locally, I use WSL2 with ubuntu.

We are planning to review all our image and provide better format with a compressed version et a webp version.

For now the objective was to use TunyPNG (https://tinypng.com/developers/reference/dotnet) to provide a compressed and webp version from the original image and use Imagesharp to resize these versions in the different dimensions that exists.

The first tests were successfull but I found a problem. I had an original transparent PNG (587x444) with filesize of 244k. The compressed version is 70k and webp converted is 16k using TinyPNG API.

The process after is to resize these versions and then i have a problem. The webp version resized to 581x439 using Imagesharp library has a filesize of 266k.

Here is the part of the code :

```
...
using var image = Image.Load(absoluteFilePath, out var format);
image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(width, height));
using var fileStream = new FileStream(convertedAbsolutePath, FileMode.Create);
await image.SaveAsync(fileStream, format);
...
```

I tried to force webp encoder and decoder but no amelioration.
With an image without transparent background, I don't have this problem.
If I use TinyPNG to do the resize, i don't have this problem and the filesize is 14k.

Is there some configurations to change or is it a problem with the Imagesharp library ?

Answer (score 2):

You can compress the image more when you use a `IImageEncoder` in the `SaveAsync`instead of the format. For Webp the encoder would be `WebpEncoder`. That has a few properties that you can change for example the `NearLosslessQuality` or `Quality`, which you can decrease to get a smaller file size. If you want to use the same method to process multiple formats you can save them as `IImageEncoder` and put that in `SaveAsync`. An example how you could do that is the following:

```cs
using var image = Image.Load(absoluteFilePath, out var format);
image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(width, height));
var encoder = GetImageEncoder(format);
using var fileStream = new FileStream(convertedAbsolutePath, FileMode.Create);
await image.SaveAsync(fileStream, encoder);
```

Where `GetImageEncoder(IImageFormat format)` is defined the following:

```cs
static IImageEncoder GetImageEncoder(IImageFormat format) {
    if(format is WebpFormat) {
        return new WebpEncoder() {
            Quality = 20,
            NearLosslessQuality = 50,
        };
    } else if(format is PngFormat) {
        return new PngEncoder();
    }
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

The `Quality` and `NearLosslessQuality` have to be in the range between 0 and 100, where a 100 is highest Quality and 0 is the worst.

Comment: I thought to this method but I don't want to reduce more and more the quality. When the WebP image isn't transparent, the "normal" WebpEncoder is sufficient and the resized images are smaller than the original Webp. I thought then to reduce quality only if I can detect transparency but it's a bit overkill. It's why I thought to a buggy process with ImageSharp WebpEncoder when the image contains transparency. The purpose was to use ImageSharp to reduce time processing and reduce calls to TinyPNG.

Comment: On GitHub is an issue from this august that mentions a similar problem(https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/issues/2216) and it is solved with using the nightly build. Sadly the last release was in June. Maybe compiling the current version on GitHub and using that solves your problem.

Comment: I tested with the nightly build alpha-0.70 by upgrading to .NET6 and I don't have this problem. Just need to check now all my code for .NET6. 
Thanks for your help ;)